# Truncate a string with the remaining space

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list where each li element contains two div inside one div "main" :

- div "main" has a fixed width (saying 200px),
- div "part1" has a variable width (that of text and image that contains)

=> I wish text inside div "part2" had as width that of div "main" less div "part1" (the remaining space)

EX:

```
...
<li>
   <div class="main">   
          <div class="part1">A</div>
          <div class="part2">BlaBlaBla</div>
   </div>   
</li>
<li>
   <div class="main">   
          <div class="part1">ABC</div>
          <div class="part2">BlaBlaBla</div>
   </div>   
</li>
<li>
   <div class="main">   
          <div class="part1">ABCDE</div>
          <div class="part2">BlaBlaBla</div>
   </div>   
</li>
...
```

It should display:

```
A BlaBla...
ABC BlaB...
ABCDE Bl...
```

I tried but it doesn't work :

```
$(function(){
  $(".part1").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $len = 0;
    var $len = $this.outerWidth();
    var $lenParent =$this.parent().outerWidth();        
    var newText2 = $this.next('.part2').text().substring(0,$lenParent-$len); 
    $this.next('.part2').innerHtml(newText2+"...");
  });
});
```

Comment: How about a parent with a fixed width and with [text-overflow: ellipsis](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html) and width the elements being inline instead of block.

Comment: @epascarello: You should add your comment as an answer for future users and I can delete mine then, which would be more appropriate I think as you are the one that mentioned it.

Comment: text-overflow: ellipsis doesn't work for all browsers (especially firefox), that's why I prefered a JS solution if possible...

Comment: @Anon: Not sure where you heard that from but according to the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-overflow it seems to be compatible with FF. The docs are slightly out of date I guess cause it still works in the latest Chrome and IE too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `display: inline` of `Thinking Sites`'s answer and the ellipse styles as suggested by `epascarello` this complete solution will now work:

```
.main{
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.part1, .part2{
    display: inline;
}
```

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/2PAJG/2/)

Comment: As I said before, text-overflow: ellipsis doesn't work for all browsers, a JS solution may be better...

Comment: @Anon: Can you point out the browser you must support in which the above doesn't work? I tested the above on the latest version of FF, Chrome and IE and they all show fine. If some CSS is not compatible with a browser the first port of call should be a CSS work-around. For what you are trying to do the script solution should the the very last option.

Comment: You're right it seems to work but now I need to apply "padding-top:13px;" to ".part2". The problem now is that ".part2" is "display: inline;" and I can't do any padding on it.

Comment: @Anon: Your `.main` is now your style for the data rows. Add `padding-top: 13px;` to the `.main` styles which works.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JavaScript for this, it can be done with styles.  Change the css for part1 and part2 to display:inline

```
.part1,.part2
{
    display:inline;
}
```